# I am not able to show Modal by calling the function using onClick prop

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-hooks

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Header from './Header'
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import {Modal} from 'react-bootstrap';
import Dialog1 from './Dialog1';

const Assessment = () => {

    const[div2visibility, setdiv2visibility] = useState("invisible");
   

    const showDialog1 = () => {
        return(
            <Modal>
                <Modal.Header>Here will be the image and close button</Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>Here will be the message</Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>Here will be the button for re-assessment</Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Header/>
            <div className="d-flex flex-row">
                <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-start m-3 mx-5">
                    <div className='m-2 mx-5 visible' style={{borderRadius: "15px", padding: "10px", paddingRight:"25px", backgroundColor:"#00CCFF"}}>
                        <h5 className='font-weight-bold'>Are you having any of these following:-</h5>
                        <div className='d-flex flex-row'>
                            <ul>
                                <li>Extremely difficult to breath</li>
                                <li>Severe Chest pain.</li>
                                <li>Having a tough time awakening</li>
                                <li>Losing consciousness</li>
                            </ul>
                            <Button onClick={() => {showDialog1(); console.log("onclick worked!")}}
                             className="mx-5 my-4 align-content-around" 
                             variant="contained" 
                            style={{maxWidth: "30px", maxHeight: "30px"}}>
                                Yes
                            </Button>

                            <Button onClick={e => {e.preventDefault(); setdiv2visibility("visible");}}
                            className="mx-1 my-4 align-content-around" 
                            color="white" variant="contained" 
                            style={{maxWidth: "30px", maxHeight: "30px"}}>
                                No
                            </Button>

                        </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
        )
}
export default Assessment
```

Can someone suggest me the better option to call the modal in this case also can someone tell me the reason why it was not working, I am at a beginner phase of learning react and react hooks.

Also the only reason for adding this whole code was to understand in detail what i am trying to do in this project.

Comment: Initially set the `display` of the modal none and when the button is clicked it should change to `block` or `flex` depending on what you want, It may sound difficult if yes inform me i will post the code

Answer (score 2):

This is because you aren't rendering your modal component, `showDialog` anywhere in your `Assessment` component. Based on your code you need to add the following line to conditionally render the modal on clicking the button

```
{ div2visibility==='visible' && <showDialog1/> }
```

This will render the modal on clicking the button however it's not the perfect solution. You should handle closing and opening of modal through its own local state and pass the parent state as props. The React-Bootstrap Modal component takes in a `show` and `handleClose` as props that you can use to control opening state of your modal.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Header from './Header'
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import {Modal} from 'react-bootstrap';
import Dialog1 from './Dialog1';

const Assessment = () => {

    const[open,setOpen] = useState(false); //initially modal is closed
   

    const showDialog1 = ({open,setOpen}) => {
        return(
            <Modal show={open} handleClose={()=>{setOpen(false)}>
                <Modal.Header>Here will be the image and close button</Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>Here will be the message</Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>Here will be the button for re-assessment</Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div>
         {open && <showDialog1 open={open} setOpen={setOpen} /> }
            <Header/>
            <div className="d-flex flex-row">
                <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-start m-3 mx-5">
                    <div className='m-2 mx-5 visible' style={{borderRadius: "15px", padding: "10px", paddingRight:"25px", backgroundColor:"#00CCFF"}}>
                        <h5 className='font-weight-bold'>Are you having any of these following:-</h5>
                        <div className='d-flex flex-row'>
                            <ul>
                                <li>Extremely difficult to breath</li>
                                <li>Severe Chest pain.</li>
                                <li>Having a tough time awakening</li>
                                <li>Losing consciousness</li>
                            </ul>
                            <Button onClick={() => {showDialog1(); console.log("onclick worked!")}}
                             className="mx-5 my-4 align-content-around" 
                             variant="contained" 
                            style={{maxWidth: "30px", maxHeight: "30px"}}>
                                Yes
                            </Button>

                            <Button onClick={e => {e.preventDefault(); setOpen(true);}}
                            className="mx-1 my-4 align-content-around" 
                            color="white" variant="contained" 
                            style={{maxWidth: "30px", maxHeight: "30px"}}>
                                No
                            </Button>

                        </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
        )
}
export default Assessment
```

It's explained quite well on the docs. https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/modal/#modals